# SwiftUI - Button Action not getting activated

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI and trying to make a Button work.

I am using XCode 12.4 on macOS Catalina 10.15.

Below is the code that I tried, and used 3 different forms of creating buttons.
None of them are working.

I did DEBUG PREVIEW, opened the CONSOLE, and don't see any messages on the CONSOLE.
I tried using debugger, and it shows the control going into the print() statement(s), but nothing is actually getting printed.

What am I missing here?

```
    VStack {

        Button("My Button - 1") {
            print("Click - 1")
        }
        
        Button(action: {
                print("Click-2")
               }){
                    Text("My Button - 2")
               }

        Button(action: {
                print("Click - 3")
               },
               label: {
                    Text("My Button - 3")
               })
    }
```

Comment: You’re using the canvas, yes? For some reason the canvas doesn’t print any print statements to the console. If you use the simulator then you’ll probably find that everything is working perfectly. Canvas seems to operate the same as the simulator is most ways but printing to console is one thing it doesn’t do

Comment: Did you put any filter in the Xcode console?

Comment: Your answer helped me @rlong405. I was able to see the print statements' output when I use the Simulator.